# AWS Lambda timeouts when requesting internet resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I’m doing a small app using serverless. I’m simply writing some webscraping in an aws lambda in order to retrieve some data with an API Gateway
The problem is, my lambda returns a timeout (changed the timeout to 30s just to be sure) and I have no clue how to debug this in the context of serverless.

Here is my lambda :

```
import json
from lambda_decorators import cors_headers
import requests


@cors_headers
def handler(event, context):
    print("Was called with params : " + str(event))
    teamId = event["queryStringParameters"]['team_id']
    print(teamId)
    body = callNbaStatsApi(teamId)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': body
    }


def callNbaStatsApi(teamId):
    print("Start callNbaStatsApi")
    nbaStatsUrl = 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/teamdashboardbygeneralsplits?DateFrom=&DateTo=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season={0}&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&Split=general&TeamID={1}&VsConference=&VsDivision='
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0',
        'x-nba-stats-origin': 'stats',
        'Referer': 'https://stats.nba.com/',
    }
    url = nbaStatsUrl.format('2019-20', teamId)
    print(url)
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(r)
    print("End callNbaStatsApi")
    return r.json()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(callNbaStatsApi('1610612749'))
```

I notice two things :

- When calling the python script on my own laptop the request works and print the nba data.
- When the request goes to http://www.google.com it does work inside of the aws lambda environment.

With all this, I suppose there is something that makes https://stats.nba.com unavailable but I don’t know what.

Also, since it can be a problem, I have no VPC configuration on my lambda

The real question here is simply : how would you work to debug such a behavior ?

Thank you for your time !

Comment: Two things could be tried. 1. Create lambda in a different region and check if other region(s) are also timing out. 2. Run the code on regular ec2 instance to check if this is lambda specific issue or not.

Comment: First you should set timeout to your [requests.get](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts).
You should have Api Gateway timeouts(default 30s) > Lambda timeout > requests.method(timeout=).
The try it with other stats from nba & see if it works. I'll suggest putting debugs/logs (print on your code) & view them on the CloudWatch->CloudWatch Logs->Log groups->/aws/lambda/lambda_name. You could also use AWS Cloud9 which is an IDE within an EC2 and you can import & run lambda's from there. Here is an youtube video of [Cloud9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmEMBxfYtf4)

Comment: Hey David! I'm experiencing a similar issue and wonder if you were ever able to solve this. I'm noticing that the first request I make to a website fails. Then after the lambda has made one request and is warm all subsequent requests succeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just interested in looking at debugging lambda scripts, the best place to start is the cloudwatch logs. Via the console, you can go directly to the service and find the respective lambda or just go onto your lambda, click the monitoring tab and choose "view logs in cloudwatch".

Once you can view your logs its up to you to include the appropriate error handling within your script and isolate the error and at what point it timeouts.

Your script looks fine, without testing it, so would depend if your packaging your lambda, have enough memory and whether the event your passing is valid?

Comment: I did watch the cloud watch logs. That's why I know it's the request to stats.nba.com stays stuck and then the lambda returns a timeout. (Thanks to the print I wrote everywhere)

I don't know python much so I don't know how I can handle the `requests.get(url, headers=headers)` to give me information as to why it fails.